# Nodejs response to API request after data processing is done

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, rabbitmq

In my current project, my nodeJs/express will receive a HTTP request through a route.

Once received, node will then use NightmareJS to perform webscraping and subsequently execute a python script that further process the data.

Lastly, it would then update this data into MongoDB.

Everything takes about 5mins.

What I am trying to achieve is to allow my front-end to somehow receive an acknowledgement that the request was put through. But also receive an update when the above process is completed and the database is updated.

I have looked into using Long polling or socket.io. However, I don't know which one I should use or how. Or should I use rabbitMQ instead? Putting the response that it is complete into the queue while my front-end constantly querying this queue.

Comment: https://pusher.com/docs/channels

Answer (score 1):

1. Long polling or socket.io are similar, socket.io has Long polling fallback if WS not supported
2. rabbitMQ is quite different, you cannot use rabbitMQ protocal in browser, so you need a client app, not a web
3. socket.io is excellent and go well along express, still there are other options, SSE (server send events), firebase. You need to feel them before you choose one, they are not that hard if you follow their official guide

4.some of my opensource might help

https://github.com/postor/sse-notify-suite

https://github.com/postor/node-realtime-db

5. benefits of each solution

   - ajax + server cache: simple
   - long pull: low latency
   - SSE: low latency, event based
   - socket.io: low latency, event based, high throug put, double direction, long pull fall back

Comment: Would you think that using socket.io for my above scenario overkill? From what i see people use socket.io for real time update, which, is what i want, but i only want it to update when the above process is completed, which is nothing like a real time chat room example.

Comment: @Herman I think just ajax every 30 second can fix your issue, and is the easist way. but I'm not really into your use case  and this is stackoverflow where most viewers are geeks, is it too low if I suggest so?

Comment: Im currently using Axios in my frontend in react. I initially thought of that, but i felt that storing a global variable in Nodejs e.g. var Status = completed/loading seems to be bad practice (Not sure about this). Would you recommend that? 

In other words, updating the global variable only when the process is completed, and having my frontend constantly querying this route every 30 seconds?

Comment: It is OK if the project is small or not  official, or say never need maintian, still use a varible inside a module is better than global @Herman

Comment: It is an official project. Would you recommend against it and use socket.io instead?

Comment: I will list benefits with each solution in the answer above, choose which is on you